# Bootstrap Scrollspy Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

My code

```
$("#navbar-collapse ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

   // store hash
   var hash = this.hash;

   // prevent default anchor click behavior
   e.preventDefault();

   // animate
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
     }, 300, function(){

       // when done, add hash to url
       // (default click behaviour)
       window.location.hash = hash;
     });

});
```

Here is my header html structure

```
<header class="main-header">
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Testing</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Scrollspy Testing</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">See all products</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Testing Info</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#support">Support</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Any idea my I'm always getting that error when clicking the dropdown menu of bootstrap

Comment: Possibly that you don't have that element that's why it's returning `top` of undefined. It would be better if you include your html.

Comment: Ok, I don't see elements that have an ID of `blog`, `about`, `support`, etc.,. So when you click `<a href="#blog">Blog</a>` it will look for an element with an ID of `blog` which currently it can't find one. Or did you just included a part your html?

Comment: Yup it is included in the body section. I solved it by adding id in my <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> and target that element in my scripts. Now I just want to add a little check in my script if the hash has a value.